# Moq with Autofac Func<Owned<IClass>>

Tags: c#, moq, autofac

I'm trying to swtich some code I have to use Owned Instances instead of passing around the container.

```
public class SyncManager
{
    private Func<Owned<ISynchProcessor>> _syncProcessor = null;

    public SyncManager(Func<Owned<ISynchProcessor>> syncProcessor)
    {
        _syncProcessor = syncProcessor;
    }

    private void Handle()
    {
        using (var service = _syncProcessor())
        {
            service.Value.Process();   
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to Moq the Func< Owned> and inject it but the calls to _syncProcessor() don't resolve anything So I tried this.

```
Mock<ITimer> timer = new Mock<ITimer>();
Mock<Func<Owned<ISynchProcessor>>> syncProcessor = new Mock<Func<Owned<ISynchProcessor>>>();
Mock<Owned<ISynchProcessor>> proc = new Mock<Owned<ISynchProcessor>>();

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    timer = new Mock<ITimer>();
    syncProcessor = new Mock<Func<Owned<ISynchProcessor>>>();
    syncProcessor.Setup(item => item.Invoke()).Returns(() => proc.Object);
}
```

but that gives me a run time error that it can't cast object of type System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN to type System.Linq.InvocationExpression

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I think I got a little Mock happy on this. There's no reason to be mocking out the Func. Doing this seems to have me back on track.

```
    Func<Owned<ISynchProcessor>> syncProcessor;
    Mock<ISynchProcessor> proc = new Mock<ISynchProcessor>();

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {        
        syncProcessor = () => new Owned<ISynchProcessor>(proc.Object, new Mock<IDisposable>().Object);         
    }
```

Now I can just pass the concrete Func into my classes and have it return me the class that I really wanted to Mock, my processor, and validate that it's calls are being done and disposed.

Comment: very nice :) that's a very clean way of handling it