# Inheriting from Owned<T>

Tags: c#, autofac

I am using WebAPI with Autofac and starting a long running task (fire and forget stuff) which will be alive after the lifetime of HTTP request. Therefore, I would like to prevent the `ApiController` to automatically dispose the object which consists the long running task, after `ApiController` lifetime ends.

In the Web API controller I would like to use `Owned<T>` class in order to inject one of the dependencies without binding it to the `LifeTimeScope` of the `ApiController` instance. It seems `Owned<T>` is a good choice for that, but I would like inherit from it in order to have virtual (polymorphic) `Value` property which I can mock with the Moq library.

However, when I inherit from `Owned<T>` autofac does not recognize (due to the reflection?) my `MyOwned<T>` and throws the exception below.

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'autofak.Meta' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Func'2[System.Int32,autofak.MyOwned'1[autofak.Root]] root' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Func'2[System.Int32,autofak.MyOwned'1[autofak.Root]])'.

This is my top-level class which depends on Root class.

```csharp
class Meta
{
    public MyOwned<Root> Root { get; private set; }

    public Meta(Func<int, MyOwned<Root>> root)
    {
        Root = root(2);
    }
}
```

My registration code is below:

```csharp
var container = new ContainerBuilder();

container.RegisterType<child>();
container.RegisterType<grandchild>();
container.RegisterType<Root>();
container.RegisterType<Meta>();

var builder = container.Build();
```

Is it possible to inherit from Owned and make it work or should I try a different approach?

**Update:**

Besides the accepted solution, I also followed a different path by creating a `SingleInstance()` factory in order to create new `LifeTimeScope` objects from the root/application lifetimescope. Similar to `Owned<T>` class I created a new class which also stores this new lifetime (created from root lifetime scope) for each task and makes it possible to call `Dispose()` as in the `Owned<T>`.

Comment: My guess is, you'll need to register your `MyOwned<T>` class with the container similar to how `Owned<T>` is configured.

Comment: I think with `Owned<T>` we do not need a special registration other than registering the types, do we?

Comment: Yeah, it's built-in for `Owned<T>`, but yours isn't.  It shouldn't be too complicated to find where `Owned<T>` is registered in Autofac's source and basically duplicate that for your class.

Comment: It's registered [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/41044d7d1a4fa277c628021537d5a12016137c3b/src/Autofac/Features/OwnedInstances/OwnedInstanceRegistrationSource.cs) using a `IRegistrationSource`.

Comment: Do you mean just copying this piece of code to my project?

Comment: Pretty much, replacing references to `Owned<T>` with your own class.

Comment: In `ContainerBulder.RegisterDefaultAdapters` which is called by overloaded `Build` (private) in `ContainerBuilder` the registration of `OwnedInstanceRegistrationSource` is done. I tried to convert the output of `Build` and tried to add my custom `MyOwnedRegistrationSource`, but this requires extra classes and extension methods from the source code. May be I am overlooking, but it doesn't seem to be the best way. :(

Comment: If you want to inherit from `Owned<T>` you will have to create your own `IRegistrationSource`, another option would be not to inherit from `Owned<T>` but let `MyOwned<T>` have a dependency on `Owned<T>` and register `MyOwned<T>` using the `RegisterGeneric` method. BTW could you explain the issue you encounter by mocking `Owned<T>`

Comment: How can I add a new `IRegistrationSource` without changing the source code Autofac. So you say `MyOwned<T>` will be a wrapper for the original `Owned<T>` which holds a reference to? `Value` property of `Owned<T>` is not virtual, so I cannot mock it by using Moq in order to inject a custom (stub/mock) object to return from it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with *Moq* but the default constructor of `Owned<T>` may allows *Moq* to provide the instance ? Could you share your *Moq* test implementation ? This question may also help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861544/moq-with-autofac-funcownediclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want would be to create a new component that uses a `Owned<T>` instead of inheriting from `Owned<T>`

```
public interface IOwned<T> : IDisposable
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class MyOwned<T> : IOwned<T>
{
    public MyOwned(Owned<T> owned)
    {
        this._owned = owned;
    }

    private readonly Owned<T> _owned;

    public virtual T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this._owned.Value;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._owned.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then register your component using the `RegisterGeneric` method and `ExternallyOwned`.

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyOwned<>))
        .As(typeof(IOwned<>))
        .ExternallyOwned();
```

You need to declare it as `ExternallyOwned` because without this *Autofac* will try to dispose this component at the end of its `ILifetimeScope` and the goal of `Owned<T>` is to let you decide when you dispose the component.

Another option would be to create your own `Owned<T>` component which is a lot more complex because you will need to implement `IRegistrationSource` to manage the child `ILifetimeScope` created by the `Owned<T>` component.

Comment: @Cryil Durand : It is a nice solution. Also, I tried something different. I created a new interface/object like IOwned/MyOwned without inheriting from Owned but copying the implementation of it. My main goal is creating a lifetime independent from the one for the HTTP request in WebAPI. So I created a factory the object (with `SingleInstance()` which creates nested lifetimes from the root) I would like to inject and pass it to the controller. Then I call `Dispose()` manually on my custom `Owned<T>` class. I like your solution thanks.

Comment: @Deniz Could you update your question to include your changes ?